# Android-GridView Padding problem

Tags: android, gridview, android-layout, imageview, padding

Im working on a app where im loading an image into the `GridView`... My problem now is
when im using the `imageView.setPadding(10,10,10,10)` its working fine for HTC Hero but in case of Motorola Droid they are overlapping each other...
How to make the padding to be common for all mobile...
Here is my code..

```
package com.android.sampleDesign1;
import android.content.Context;
import android.text.Layout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TicTacToeAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

public ImageView imageView;

private Context mContext;
private Integer mThumbIds = R.drawable.images;    

private Integer image;

public TicTacToeAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;

}

public int getCount() {
    return 9;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}



public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {    
    image = mThumbIds;  

    if (convertView == null) {
        imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setImageResource(image);             
        imageView.setPadding(10,10,10,10);          

     } else {
        imageView = (ImageView) convertView;           
        imageView.setImageResource(image);          
    }               
    return imageView;
  }   

}
```

I have also tried to use the 
    `int w = gridView.getWidth();`
    `int myViewWidth = Math.round(W * .12f);`

and also i tried with the 
    `LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);`
`lp.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom);`
`imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);`

So is there anyother way to do.. Or am i wrong anywhere..
Help me out..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather defining the padding in `pixels`, you need to define it in `dips` (density independent pixels) and then convert the `dips` to `pixels` at run time.

So you would need to do something similar to

```
private static final float PADDING_IN_DP = 10.0f; // 1 dip = 1 pixel on an MDPI device
private final int mPaddingInPixels;

public TicTacToeAdapter(Context context) {
    ....
    // Convert the dps to pixels
    final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    mPaddingInPixels = (int) (PADDING_IN_DP * scale + 0.5f);
}

...
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    ...
    if (convertView == null) {
        ...
        imageView.setPadding(mPaddingInPixels, mPaddingInPixels, mPaddingInPixels, mPaddingInPixels);
    }
    ...
}
...
```

The `scale` you get in your constructor will differ depending on the density of the screen of the device your app is running on.

(Note: `dip` and `dp` are the same thing)